# Обработка ответа от ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Добрый день! Подскажите плз в таком вопросе. В БД хранится текст обрамленный тегами `<p></p>`. Этот текст вытаскиваю из БД с помощью ajax и вставляю в поле textarea с помощью

```
$("textarea").html(res);
```

Проблема в том что в итоге в textarea полученный текст отображается вместе с тегами `<p></p>`. Как сделать так чтоб вместо `<p>` были полноценные абзацы? 
`<p></p>` в БД специально оставил, чтоб сохранить абзацы в тексте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элемент textarea не умеет отображать html разметку. Если Вы хотите получить подобие абзацев в элементе textarea, то Вам придется заменить все эти теги на обычные переводы строк и пробелы.

```js
var str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu odio quis mauris consequat scelerisque id tempor diam.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed condimentum purus. Mauris blandit justo a laoreet blandit. Quisque sit amet ullamcorper justo. Donec mollis convallis odio sit amet aliquet. Maecenas vitae purus et elit dapibus efficitur. Duis venenatis neque ut tincidunt gravida. Donec feugiat mauris non tincidunt suscipit.</p><p>Nunc euismod ullamcorper risus at semper. Morbi sit amet magna posuere, malesuada ligula vel, efficitur nulla. Donec non ipsum non sem porta finibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec ultrices aliquet arcu, dictum vestibulum tortor.</p>";
var edited = str.replace(/<\/p>/g,"\n").replace(/<p>/g,"    ")
$("#textarea").html(edited);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea" cols="80" rows="12"></textarea>
```

Comment: подскажите что означает /g ?

Comment: @aleks_sk, флаг регулярного выражения для глобального поиска и замены. В противном случае он заменит только один первый найденный элемент и дальше не пойдет: http://javascript.ru/String/replace

Comment: Спасибо, вам за ответ, подскажите пожалуйста как вставить здесь код, а то я на этом сайте впервые

Comment: @aleks_sk, там где инструменты редактирования(жирный, курсив, ссылка, изображение, etc) при создании сообщения вверху есть фигурные скобки `{ }` для выделения кода или `символ страницы с угловыми скобками` для создания запускаемого примера как у меня в ответе. Если в комментариях, то нажмите "справка" справа от окна комментария, когда его непосредственно пишите.

Comment: ок, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @aleks_sk пожалуйста) Если считаете, что у вопроса есть решение, отмечайте правильный ответ галочкой напротив правильного ответа(под голосами). Это принесет отвечающему балы репутации и даст понять другим участникам, что проблема спрашивающего решена. Как-то так: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Для этого вам нужно установить на сайт визуальный редактор (WYSIWYG), например [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com). И в таком случае - при вставке html-кода в текстовую область - ее будет подхватывать визуальный редактор и оформлять как вам нужно, с возможностью и редактировать.

Comment: добавил ckeditor. Теперь не получается вставить ответ в этот wysiwyg. Он формирует свою разметку, но я так понимаю что его нет в DOM и поэтому jquery не находит нужный элемент и не вставляет ответ.    $(".cke_editable > body > p").html(res);

Comment: У визуальных редакторов на этот случай есть API, у Ckeditor тоже. Вы можете вставить в него код командой `CKEDITOR.instances['mytextarea1'].setData(html)`, где `mytextarea1` - это id вашей текстовой области, к которой был привязан Ckeditor, а `html` - ваш код, полученный через аякс.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Теперь стоит задача отправить аяксом отредактированный текст. Не подскажите как это реализовать? А то я в документации ckeditor не могу разобраться((